# Finding the closest object (barrier) to the player

Tags: java, oop, object, coordinates, distance

I have a program that checks distance and whether or not the player has collided with a barrier. I now am trying to calculate which barrier in the array of barriers is the closest to the moving player, then returning the index of that barrier.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static int closestBarrier(GameObject object, GameObject[] barriers)
// TODO stub
{
    int closest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < barriers.length - 1; i++) {

        if (Math.sqrt((object.getX() - barriers[i].getX())
                * (object.getX() - barriers[i].getX()))
                + ((object.getY() - barriers[i].getY()) * (object.getY() - barriers[i]
                        .getY())) <= Math
                .sqrt((object.getX() - barriers[i + 1].getX())
                        * (object.getX() - barriers[i + 1].getX()))
                + ((object.getY() - barriers[i + 1].getY()) * (object
                        .getY() - barriers[i + 1].getY()))) {

            closest = i;
        } else
            closest = i + 1;

    }

    return closest;
}
```

I am still new to java so I understand what I already have probably isn't very efficient or the best method of doing it (or even right at all!?).

Comment: Yucky... Use variables to store the result of the nested calculations, it's quite *undebuggable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor it a wee bit simpler like so:

```
public static int closestBarrier(GameObject object, GameObject[] barriers)
    {
        int closest = -1;
        float minDistSq = Float.MAX_VALUE;//ridiculously large value to start
        for (int i = 0; i < barriers.length - 1; i++) {
            GameObject curr = barriers[i];//current
            float dx = (object.getX()-curr.getX()); 
            float dy = (object.getY()-curr.getY()); 
            float distSq = dx*dx+dy*dy;//use the squared distance
            if(distSq < minDistSq) {//find the smallest and remember the id
                minDistSq = distSq;
                closest = i;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
```

This way you're doing less distance checks (your version does two distance checks per iteration) and also you only need the id, not the actual distance, so you can gain a bit of speed by not using `Math.sqrt()` and simply using the squared distance instead.

Another idea I can think of depends on the layout. Say you have a top down vertical scroller, you would start by checking the y property of your obstacle. If you have a hash of them or a sorted list, for an object at the bottom of the screen you would start loop from the largest y barrier to the smallest. Once you found the closest barriers on the Y axis, if there are more than 1 you can check for the closest on the x axis. You wouldn't need to use square or square root as you're basically splitting the checks from 1 in 2D per barrier to 2 checks in 1D, narrowing down your barrier and discarding far away barriers instead of checking against **every single object** all the time.

An even more advanced version would be using [space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Spatial_partitioning) but hopefully you won't need it for a simple game while learning.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I completely understand how you've rewritten it, makes much more sense and more efficient. It is almost working, however I still am failing one test and I can't figure out why. Here is the test: (my result is barrier 2 is closest but in fact it's barrier 1 that is)

`player.setX(12);
player.setY(20);
assertEquals("Player closest to second barrier",2,            Submission.closestBarrier(player,barriers));`

Comment: @danboy I'm not familiar with the rest of your code and setup, so it's kind of hard to work out the issue with precision. Using the distance formular works best with circle/square shapes. I'm assuming you might be dealing with irregular shaped objects and the centroid of the barrier is not the closest point in the direction of the test object. It's better if you visualize this.

Comment: I'm using circles and my distance formula is this

`double b1Dist = Math.sqrt((obOneX - obTwoX) * (obOneX - obTwoX)
    + ((obOneY - obTwoY) * (obOneY - obTwoY)));
  double b1DistTwo = b1Dist - objectOneRadius;
  b1DistFinal = b1DistTwo - objectTwoRadius;

  return b1DistFinal;`

Sorry for continuing to ask you but thanks for your time!